# Hibernate table mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I have one table in database called Institute in which institute related details are stored. One column in this table is Institute_type_id which is FK of Institute_type table with PK Institute_type_id. The table institute_type contains one more column Institute_type_name.
There is one page in JSP which list down the institute based on search. And there is also section to "REFINE YOUR SEARCH" where user can select institute_type and can narrow the search.
I have implemented using Spring MVC and used model attribute to store the user values and used criteria search to query in database.
Lets example -
Institute (table)
Id  name          insitute_type place
101   High School   1           ABC

Institute_type(table)
ID Type
1  School
2  College

Models
Institute.java

```
@Column(name="INSTITUTE_TYPE")
private Integer instituteType;

//Code for other column and getter and setter
```

Institute_type.java

```
@Column(name="ID")
private Integer ID;

@Column(name="TYPE")
private String type;

//code for setter and getter
```

Note - the relation b/w Institute and Institute_type table is one to many. One Institute may have more than one institute type. let The institute "ABC" may be school and +2 School (11th and 12th std) both or may be only one. A institute may be a +2 school only or combination of + School and College. etc.
Requirement - When user select institute_type to narrow the search query must use a criteria to narrow the search.
Problem - If I am using mapping one to one , Hibernate used left outer join so those institute which does match with institute_type also in search list. How to implement the solution of the problem in hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I think the relation is Many To Many if one institute may have multiple institute types. I guess the same institute type can be used by multiple institutes. Furthermore, why don't you map instituteType to the Institute_type class? If you map it to the class you can use HQL/JPQL or the Criteria API to create queries with joins and a filter. In what way do you get your data now?